# How to set highlights for new windows except from specific filetypes in neovim?

Tags: neovim

I'm trying to create a highlight for trailing spaces and tabs for all windows in NeoVim, but I'm having problems to handle exceptions. Basically I want to set it for all windows except terminal windows (which I use the plugin toggleterm) and the help page.

From reading the docs I realised that the `WinNew` or `WinEnter` events are fired before the `filetype` is set, so it basically inherits the filetype from the current window. Because of that my check never works properly. Is there a way to make this check work? I thought of using buffer events, but then I'd be executing this many times unnecessarily since the `match` applies for the window and not for the buffer.

```lua
vim.cmd('highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=lightyellow guibg=lightyellow')
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'VimEnter', 'WinNew' }, {
    desc = 'Highlight all tabs and trailing whitespaces',
    pattern = '*',
    callback = function()
        -- TODO: implement blacklist
        if vim.bo.filetype ~= 'toggleterm' or vim.bo.filetype ~= 'help' then
            vim.fn.matchadd('ExtraWhitespace', '\\s\\+$\\|\\t')
        end
    end,
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal can be opened in any existing window, and so you can't tell this beforehand and can't blacklist anything.

Instead, remove the match after terminal has been opened.

```
augroup mystuff | au!
    autocmd VimEnter,WinNew 2match Todo /\s\+$\|\t/
    autocmd TermOpen,TerminalWinOpen * 2match none
    "       ^-- Nvim ^-- Vim
augroup end
```

Comment: Yeah. I think removing the match is a good workaround. I can make it trigger from the filetype instead. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Augusto Remember that `&filetype` is never set for regular terminal(s).

Comment: yes but the plugin toggleterm sets it... The way I work is that a terminal is always in it own window, so it should work fine.